# basic firebase rules and search

Tags: firebase, react-native

Hi i'm trying to make a simple recipe react native app for school.

I am quit new to react native and noSQL. So how do i query in react native to my firebase?

what i want to do is to search for a specific product and to get all the recipes with this product in them. And the next thing i want to do is to be able to 
add another product and find a recipe that has both of them and so on.

I have this setup for my firebase:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQN5U.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** For more complex queries I recommend using [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

**On your question:** With your data structured like that, it is impossible to achieve what you want using queries provided by firebase sdk. The problem is that your recipes have those `ingredient1: 5505`, `ingredient2: 4404` ... change those to `5505: true`, `4404: true`. Then use the sdk like this:

```
const getRecipesForProduct = async (productName) => {
    const product = await firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild("name").equalTo(productName).once('value').then(snap => {...snap.val(), uid: snap.key()})
    const recipes = await firebase.database().ref('recipe').orderByChild(product.uid).equalTo(true).once('value').then(snap => snap.val())
    // do something with recipes
}
```